# I need help to calculate Penney's game probabilities

Tags: python

I want to change this code in order to compare every single one of the combinations seen in (estrategies) withouth having to write the same code 56 times. At the moment, the program only compares (0,0,0) and (1,1,1) but i want him to compare all strategies against eachother (but not with itself). I don't know if I should use a matrix or something similar. I appreciate the help.

```
import random

estrategia=[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]

CCC=0
XXX=0

for jugades in range (10000) :
    llista = [random.randint (0, 1) for x in range (100)]
    for i in range(len(llista)):
        if i+2 >= len(llista):
            break
        if llista[i] == 0 and llista[i+1] == 0 and llista[i-1] == 0:
            CCC+=1
            break
        if llista[i] == 1 and llista[i+1] == 1 and llista[i-1] == 1:
            XXX+=1
            break

print (f'CCC equals {CCC}.')
print (f'XXX equals {XXX}.')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have 28 combinations, not 56: (A, B) is the same combination as (B, A).  Did you mean *permutation*?

```
for strategy_a, strategy_b in itertools.combinations(estrategia, 2):
```

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) for details.

Example:

```
import itertools
                 
for a, b in itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3, 4], 2):
    print(a, b)
```

Output:

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
```